# Ria services GetQuery - limit data to Top 3000 rows

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Looking to see if anybody used Top method to limit the rows returned from GetQuery. I have a query as follows

var userQueues = this.ObjectContext.SelfSvcUserQueues.Where(t => t.QueueUserID.StartsWith(filterUserId)).OrderBy(t => t.QueueUserID);

when I change this to

var userQueues = this.ObjectContext.SelfSvcUserQueues.**Top(3000).**Where(t => t.QueueUserID.StartsWith(filterUserId)).OrderBy(t => t.QueueUserID);

now rows returned so I'm missing something obvious or not using it in proper way. Searched for any usages many sites but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var userQueues = this.ObjectContext.SelfSvcUserQueues
    .OrderBy(t => t.QueueUserID)
    .Where(t => t.QueueUserID.StartsWith(filterUserId))
    .Take(3000);
```

Comment: This works, thanks for your post. Some of the people in my company were saying they don't see Top() in their version. I'm still not clear why we have 2 different methods. Here is what I observed so far. If you want Top 3000 irrespective of Order and Where use Top(), if you want to filter with this criteria use Take().